# how to update pubspec.yml file

Tags: pubspec.yaml

name: foodie_driver
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 3.2.2+10

environment:
sdk: ">=2.13.4 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
firebase_messaging: ^12.0.3
firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.2
shared_preferences: ^2.1.0
firebase_core: ^2.4.1
firebase_auth: ^4.2.4
cloud_firestore: ^3.4.5
image_picker: ^0.8.7+2
firebase_storage: ^10.3.6
progress_dialog:
git:
url: https://github.com/mostafaAbdelazim/progress_dialog.git
provider: ^6.0.5
url_launcher: ^6.1.10
intl: any
cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
uuid: ^3.0.7
video_thumbnail: ^0.5.3
path_provider: ^2.0.2
photo_view: ^0.14.0
video_player: ^2.6.1
flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.8
http: ^0.13.5
geolocator: ^9.0.2
flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.1
intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.3+1
pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
permission_handler: ^10.2.0
easy_localization: ^3.0.1
google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.5
font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1
flutter_sound: ^9.2.13
the_apple_sign_in: ^1.1.1
video_compress: ^3.1.2
location: ^4.4.0
audioplayers: ^4.0.1
paginate_firestore: ^1.0.3+1
flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.10.0
razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.4
flutter_stripe: ^9.0.0+1
mercadopago_sdk: ^1.3.0
flutter_braintree: ^3.0.0
paytm_allinonesdk: ^1.2.1
flutterwave_standard: ^1.0.7

dev_dependencies:
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0

dependency_overrides:
webview_flutter: ^4.0.7

flutter_icons:
android: true
ios: true
image_path: 'assets/images/getit.png'
flutter:

uses-material-design: true
assets:
- assets/images/
- assets/translations/
- assets/fonts/
- assets/flags/
- assets/audio/

fonts:
- family: Poppinsb
fonts:
- asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf

```
- family: Poppinsl
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf

- family: Poppinsm
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf

- family: Poppinsr
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf

- family: Poppinssb
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
```